# Como alterar a cor de vários textbox olhando somente uma condição

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando uma aplicação no *VS2015* *WindowsFormAplication* onde preciso mudar as cores dos `textbox` quando os resultado for superior, igual ou inferior ao valor zero(0).
Estou trabalhando da seguinte forma:

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(tbEntrDiferenca.Text) > 0)
  tbEntrDiferenca.BackColor = Color.Green;
if (Convert.ToDecimal(tbEntrDiferenca.Text) < 0)
  tbEntrDiferenca.BackColor = Color.Red;
tbEst2016Mat.BackColor = Color.Red;
if (Convert.ToDecimal(tbEntrDiferenca.Text) == 0)
  tbEntrDiferenca.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Vou precisar fazer essa mesma condição em vinte(20) `textbox`. Existe uma forma mais fácil do que essa?

[image: FORM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível pegar todos os `textbox` usando esta função:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        //Sua Logica
    }
}
```

Basta você inserir sua lógica dentro do bloco, ele alterará para todos. Algo assim provavelmente funcionaria:

```
 foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text) > 0)
                tb.BackColor = Color.Green;
            else if (Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text) < 0)
                tb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else 
                tb.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Luiz Pelo que eu entendi a mudança deve ser verificada em cada campo individualmente e cada mudança de forma individual, então e o código efetua a mudança baseada em apenas um valor

Comment: Eu entendi que existe uma regra geral que deve ser verificada em cada campo, acredito que o for resolva.

Comment: Pessoal, não resolveu o problema pois existe dois(2) textbox que não podem seguir essa regra. Tem como eu colocar alguma exceção ?

Comment: Esta é a maneira de fazer a interação, pode me falar qual a regra dos outros dois para eu ver o que pode ser feito? A logica resolve o problema da pergunta, porque você diz "Vou precisar fazer essa mesma condição em vinte(20) textbox"

Comment: Realmente eu utilizei as palavras erradas mas eu adicionei uma imagem do form para tentar ajudar com a solução do meu problema. Os textbox abaixo de produto e descrição não podem ser tratados com a mesma condicao do restante.

Comment: Você pode acrescentar buscar o Name do textbox e quando o name for igual aos que você quer fora da regra você simplesmente não faz nada. Ou pode também colocar os textbox dentro de um painel e so executar para os filhos do painel.

Comment: Eu entendi!! Vou tentar fazer da forma que voce explicou!! Obrigado

Comment: boa sorte, qualquer coisa estamos aê.